# dd returns permission denied even as root

Tags: centos, root, dd

I'm trying to backup a centos server using dd but I get permission denied even if I'm logged as root.

```
[root@server ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs              90G   58G   33G  64% /
none                  1.5G  4.0K  1.5G   1% /dev

[root@server ~]# dd if=/dev/vzfs of=/dev/null
dd: opening `/dev/vzfs': Permission denied
```

I don't know what to do from here, please help!

Best,

Julien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a virtual filesystem (container).  You cannot access directly even as root-- it's only available from the actual system that the virtual machine is running on.

Comment: Does this apply to Android phones and terminal emulator as well ? I'm getting the same error when `cp -f` the `/dev/block ..../proinfo` through Busybox as a root. What can I do when on Android ?